# Images are shown big on AVD?

Tags: android, scaling, android-virtual-device

Well, I set my AVD to

480 x 800 resolution ,

abstracted lcd density to 320 pixel

And my image  dimension is 207 width and 205 height and the image has set to 320 pixels per inch but it is shown very big on avd with resolution 480 x 800 and 320 dpi. Images are placed in @drawable/MDPI folder only. Here it is

[image]

[image]

Does image needs to set on 160 pixels per inch or I have to set avd size using (scale display to real size) option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have emulator of `320 dpi` which is `xhdpi`. And you are putting your images in `mdpi folder`. Now when you launch your app it looks for images in `xhdpi folder` first and it finally load images from `mdpi folder` scale them to `xhdpi density` and show them. Thats why images are coming big.

May be you can test in `mdpi density` emulator or you can support `xhdpi` in your app by having images in `xhdpi`.

Answer (score 0):

check with `android:src=""` and `android:background=""` attribute in xml file in the ImageView.

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/create_beacon" />